How do you make Javascript work in rails engine?
I have added these gems in Gemfile
gem "sprockets-rails"
gem "importmap-rails"
gem 'stimulus-rails', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.1'
gem 'hotwire-rails', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'turbo-rails', '~> 1.4'

I have added these gems in engine's gemspec
spec.add_dependency "sprockets-rails"
 spec.add_dependency  "importmap-rails"

added these pins in my importmap.rb
pin "popper", to: 'popper.js', preload: true
pin "bootstrap", to: 'bootstrap.min.js',preload:true
pin "@rails/actiontext", to: "actiontext.esm.js"
pin "my_engine/application"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js"
pin "trix"

I have added these in my engine's application.js in javascript folder
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "popper"
import "bootstrap"
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"
import "./datatables-simple-demo"
import "./scripts"

I see these imports as I inspect the view source and I get this
"imports": {
    "popper": "/assets/popper-003a40d80fd205e1fa00da117d5bdc19720ba330706eaa17f9ba9513fa502304.js",
    "bootstrap": "/assets/bootstrap.min-3389e8d94238c6aae57b91819279862a918c12e4596fd5a397c51f16df96057e.js",
    "@rails/actiontext": "/assets/actiontext.esm-328ef022563f73c1b9b45ace742bd21330da0f6bd6c1c96d352d52fc8b8857e5.js",
    "my_engine/application": "/assets/webjinny/application-572df010906ff7060796d6138c937ef5340b1bd6c59f21dcdaf6c29b12e66b26.js",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "/assets/turbo.min-dfd93b3092d1d0ff56557294538d069bdbb28977d3987cb39bc0dd892f32fc57.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "/assets/stimulus.min-dd364f16ec9504dfb72672295637a1c8838773b01c0b441bd41008124c407894.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-loading": "/assets/stimulus-loading-3576ce92b149ad5d6959438c6f291e2426c86df3b874c525b30faad51b0d96b3.js",
    "trix": "/assets/trix-686ab55c2aea8035a7f728b61ec7afedfe857f70d6279ab453da775b7469e9e8.js"
  }

But still Javascript is not working...Even the trix being imported doesn't function without CDN
